# Can I gain access by nmap?

Tags: exploit, nmap

I have a Debian machine with nginx 1.14.0 (Ubuntu), and I found an exploit, https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/linux/http/nginx_chunked_size

But, is it possible to gain access by only nmap?

Comment: Why don't you just use metasploit commands as explained in the link you provided?

Comment: Why do you want to use nmap for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nmap is a software for discover information in the network like open ports, SO versions, host discover... but as far as I know, you can't get access with nmap. You will need other aps like Armitage or aircrack-ng to exploit the vulnerabilities you found with nmap.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of the exploit... but in theory you could use the payload command of nmap to send a malicious payload to trigger an exploit and inject malicious code that reaches back to a listener you have set up to receive it.

Answer (score 0):

The nmap is a tool for vulnerability scanning and network discovery.

Active vulnerability scans generate internet traffic to target machines and ports. In this sense you connect, communicate and get access to the target infrastructure, and responses from the target infrastructure.

This also means your activity can potentially cause, or be treated as a preparation to cause, a disruption to the target infrastructure, can be detected, traced back, and investigated further.

Remember to always ask for and receive a formal, written and precise authorization before running any vulnerability tests on any infrastructure that is not fully your own.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "**No**". You can't use nmap for exploiting vulnerabilities. However you can use nmap for;

- Finding open ports and running application versions on those open ports (ex: nmap -A $TARGET)
- Testing some vulnerabilities by using nmap script engine: https://nmap.org/book/man-nse.html
- Discovering hosts alive on the network ( nmap -sn $TARGET )